# where is the viewport shading in blender 2.8?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, interface

i am trying to render my project in real time in blender 2.8 cycles but i can't change the viewport option and I can't find it  any help ? [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The icons are on the bottom toolbar in the 3D View. You can't see them because the 3D View is too narrow, so they're getting cut off.

You can move the divider between the two 3D Views to the right to reveal the icons:

[image: gif of divider in the 3D view being dragged to the right]

You can also can middle click and drag to the left on the toolbar to access the icons:

[image: gif of middle mouse click and drag on toolbar]

Comment: Is there any way to access those options without resizing the viewport? I would expect those options to be accessible via some menu or command but I cannot find anything. (I tested with Blender version 2.90)

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen You should probably ask this as a separate question (and search to see if there is already an existing question), but if you enable 'Pie menu' add-on you can access these options with 'Z'.